# How to generate pdf file from a specific type of content?

Tags: 7, files

I have a content type named "employees".

I want that when I add an employee(creating content of type employee) it should also generate a pdf file which will contain the data which I inserted during adding content.

And a link on that node appears stated that "Download the pdf".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality with [print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module. For documentation [click here](http://drupal.org/node/190171).
This module depends on the libraries you can install any of them.
1. dompdf
2. mPDF
3. TCPDF(Best in performance)
4. wkhtmltopdf

Comment: can I change the text of the link which is appearing on a node page?

Comment: I find the way to change the text of the link :)